# View class object is null inside Fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a class which implements the `View` class. I also have an `Activity` that hosts 2 Fragments.
In the `OnCreate` method of the `Fragment`, I instantiate the `View` class and pass `Activity.ApplicationContext` because it takes in a context in its constructor.

I have two methods inside the `Fragment`. One is called in the `OnCreateView` and another elsewhere in the `Fragment`. The value of the `View` class object is *not* null inside the method called in `OnCreateView`. However, when I try to access the `View` object from the other method called elsewhere in the fragment, the app fails with a `NullPointerException` pointing to the `View` object.

I don't understand why,and yet this class is instantiated in the fragment's OnCreate method.Below is my code:

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class SampleFragment : Fragment
    {
        private MyView mView;
        public override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            mView = new MyView (Activity.ApplicationContext);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //var root = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_map, container, false);

            Populate ();

            return mView;
        }

        public void Populate ()
        {
            //mView here is not null

            List<Point> points = db.GetAllPoints ();

            mView.mSampleCalculations.ClearViewElements ();

            foreach (Point lPoint in points) {
                MViewElement element = new MViewElement ();

                element .Size = MViewElement .mSize.Custom;
                element .CustomSize = 1;
                element .Shape = MViewElement .mShape.Circle;

                mView.mSampleCalculations.AddElement (element );

            }
        }

        public void CenterViewOnCoordinates()
        {
            try{
                if(mView != null) //mView is null here
                {
                    if (mView .mSampleCalculations.GetElement ("Coordinates") != null)
                    {
                        mView.CenterView (Icoordinate);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does populate do to the view?

Comment: It draws some points from a list to onto this view

Comment: I just edited it,so you can see how it does that

Comment: Just use `Activity` as a `Context`. Although that won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

About code in `OnCreate` method, `mView = new MyView (Activity.ApplicationContext);` This does not help create the View object. Another issue, it is not safe to cache/save the view object with `mView` because views in Android may be changed at any time.

You need to override the onCreateView(), as suggested by jmateo.Except with a little change:

```
// using local scope for the View object
View root = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_map, container, false)
Populate();
return root;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done Xamarin, only straight up Java but the same rules should apply. You cannot instantiate a view with the application context. You need to use the activity context and when using fragments, you need to do so in your onCreateView, not onCreate.

Your onCreateView should look similar to:

```
mView = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_map, container, false)
Populate();
return mView;
```